How do I use PowerShell instead of CertReq.exe?
I've been looking around for a while to find out how to get rid of that pesky inf-file when creating certificate requests from a command prompt.
This is a sample inf file
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"

[NewRequest]
FriendlyName = "SharePoint STS Certificate"
Subject = "CN=sts.contoso.com, O=Org, OU=Unit, L=City, S=State, C=Country"
KeyLength = 2048
KeyAlgorithm = RSA
KeyUsage = "CERT_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE | CERT_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_KEY_USAGE"
KeySpec = "AT_KEYEXCHANGE"
MachineKeySet = true
RequestType = Cert
ExportableEncrypted = true

[Strings]
szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE = "2.5.29.37"
szOID_PKIX_KP_SERVER_AUTH = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"
szOID_PKIX_KP_CLIENT_AUTH = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2"
szOID_SUBJECT_ALT_NAME2 = "2.5.29.17"

[Extensions]
%szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE%="{text}%szOID_PKIX_KP_SERVER_AUTH%,"
_continue_ = "%szOID_PKIX_KP_CLIENT_AUTH%"
%szOID_SUBJECT_ALT_NAME2% = "{text}dns=server1&dns=server2"


And certreq -new request.inf request.req would create the certificate request.
Now, it's been suggested to me, that I can actually do the same using New-SelfSignedCertificate cmdlet if combined with Export-Certificate in PowerShell.

This should do the trick, right?
# Define the parameters for the certificate

# Object Identifiers
$EKU = '2.5.29.37'  # Enhanced Key Usage OID - Purposes for the public key
$Server_Auth = '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1'
$Client_Auth = '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2'

#$SAN = '2.5.29.17'  # Subject Alternate Name OID

$CertParams = @{
    DnsName            = 'sts.contoso.com','server1'
    CertStoreLocation  = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My'
    FriendlyName       = 'SharePoint STS Certificate'
    KeyLength          = 2048
    KeyAlgorithm       = 'RSA'
    KeyUsage           = 'DigitalSignature', 'KeyEncipherment'
    Subject            = 'CN=sts.contoso.com, O=Org, OU=Unit, L=City, S=State, C=Country'
    TextExtension      = @(
         "$EKU={text}$Server_Auth,$Client_Auth"
    )
}

# Create the self-signed certificate using splatting
$CertReq = New-SelfSignedCertificate @CertParams -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(1)
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($CertReq.RawData) |
    Out-File ~\.myreq.req -Encoding ascii

And when my request has been uploaded to, and handled by a provider, a public certificate will be returned that I just import using
Import-Certificate -FilePath ~\.issued_certificate.cer -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My'
and the private key should be re-associated from the self-signed certificate to the public certificate.
Edit: This doesn't work if the Certificate Provider portal is picky :/

A self-signed certificate (what you've created and exported here) and a certificate signing request (which is what certreq -new creates) is not quite the same thing. But it might indeed do the trick, because the crucial piece of information that the signing CA needs from you is the public part of your key - which both a cert and a CSR would contain :)

I'll try it out in a while when it's time to renew the certs from one of my UAT-environments.

Didn't work with DigiCert :/
